# How to draw Feynman diagrams without using LuaLatex in Overleaf?

Tags: pdftex, tikz-feynman, feynman

I am new to drawing Feynman diagrams in Latex, however I found some sources and try to implement them. I managed to draw the diagrams using LuaLatex, however it makes changes to other things in the thesis, for example citations should be re-written somehow. So my question is following, is there some way to draw Feynman diagrams (simple ones) without using LuaLatex in Overleaf, but just with pdfLatex?

Comment: Actually, I am doing it with tikz-feynman and it doesn't compile correctly if I do not use LuaLatex.

Comment: As an alternative solution, you can draw them in standalone files, compile those to PDF and include the resulting PDFs as pictures.

Comment: if you said what errors you got someone would be able to help but there are several packages for these diagrams  see https://ctan.org/search?phrase=feynman  pick one you like

Answer (score 0):

You can draw Feynman diagrams without using LuaLatex in Overleaf, but will have a lot of warnings, but You still can compile Your document and view .pdf file, see more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuaTeX

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do not compile with LuaLatex, the Feynman diagram's vertices are misplaced.